# Django: request.session in templates

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get {{ request.session.something }} work in Django templates ( with TemplateResponse ).

Here are a bit of information I've found so far:

- First of all, I have "django.template.context_processors.request" included in my settings ( Django 1.9 ).
- If I use render from django.shortcuts then {{ request.session.something }} perfectly works in templates
- I need to use TemplateResponse, because I have a middleware and I need "process_request" and "process_template_response" to be called ( if I recall, "process_template_response" doesn't work with render from django.shortcuts )

Any suggestions what might be the problem?

The view code ( nothing special ):

```
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse as render
def coming_soon(request):
    return render(request, 'app/coming-soon.html', None)
```

Thank you in advance!
Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Please show the view code.

Comment: I'm not sure you are using tamplate response correctly as I've not used it before, but you can just add the session data to the request context dictionary just like any other variable in the view and pass it to render and the template can access it. You template can't access the request session.

Comment: Will try to do it in the middleware...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using class based views, you could make a function like

```
def get_session_thing(self):
    x = self.request.session.thing
    #stuff
    return str(x)
```

and then in the template you can do

```
{{ view.get_session_thing }}
```